# Query Help With TSQL (Join Functions)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I'm trying to do is take a guests duration of stay and multiplying it by their room rate, adding an invoice (for any purchases they may have made at the resort) and adding a dining bill to give them a total cost of their stay by guest name.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT gr.g_name, (DATEDIFF(d, r.res_checkout_date, r.res_checkin_date) * pp.rate ) + ISNULL(i.inv_amount, 0) + ISNULL(d.total_dining, 0)
FROM guest_reservation gr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice i ON gr.confirm_no = i.confirm_no
JOIN reservation r ON gr.confirm_no = r.confirm_no
JOIN price_plan pp ON r.price_plan = pp.price_plan;
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT r_confirmation_no, SUM(price) as total_dining
                 FROM dining_order do JOIN dining_menu dm ON do.item = dm.item 
                 GROUP BY r_confirmation_no, price) as d ON d.r_confirmation_no = r.confirm_no
```

When I run that query however I get the following error messages:

"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'."

Any ideas?

The above query uses the following tables:

The guest reservation table has the following columns with data:

- confirm_no
- agent_id
- g_name
- g_phone

The reservation table has the following columns with data:

- confirm_no
- credit_card_no
- res_checkin_date
- res_checkout_date
- default_villa_type
- price_plan

The invoice table has the following columns with data:

- inv_no
- inv_date
- inv_amount
- confirm_no

The price plan table has the following columns with data:

- price_plan
- rate
- default_villa_type
- bed_type

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. As you are no doubt aware, people generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax error is because of the `;` in `pp.price_plan;`.

Comment: After I take that out the query runs but it's odd, I'm getting multiple instances of guest names and various numbers for them, 

for example I'll get a guest name with 3 entries all with 3 sepearate $ amounts.

Comment: @Jon, You will have at least one row for each `guest_reservation`. Not one row for each guest. And if there are more than one `invoice` connected to one `guest_reservation` you will get more than one row for each `guest_reservation`.